# Find the view models DataContext within a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `ContentControl` with a `ContentTemplateSelector` like this

```
<Border>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyObject}" ContentTemplateSelector="{Binding MyContentTemplateSelector"}/>
</Border>
```

Within my `DataTemplate`, I want to access an `ICommand` defined in the border's `DataContext(ViewModel)`

I've tried the `FindAncestor` Mode, but I suspect that this only operates within the `DataTemplate` and not the whole `VisualTree`. This is the `XAML` code which is in the `DataTemplate`:

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Border,AncestorLevel=2}}" 
                                                                        CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
```

Any suggestions on how I can bind this command to the DataContext of my ViewModel? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ContentControl, you coul add this property :

```
Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
```

Then in your InvokeCommandAction, you bind to the tag property :

```
Command="{Binding Tag.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContentControl}}"
```